# How to process image embedded in email and resize

Tags: image-processing, xamarin.forms, mime-mail

We have code that works fine outside of Xamarin (and .Net Standard 2.0) but fails with a platform not supported error (on the Image.FromStream(...)) line when trying to execute in a Xamarin Forms application. This code processes an email that was saved in a database and tries to resize the image and then re-output the message body for consumption by a Xamarin WebView control. How can we get around this issue with Image.FromStream() not working for us?

Here's the code that does the processing (can assume ratio is 50 as an example):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts images in an email to Base64 imbedded source
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newMessage">MimeMessage that represents the loaded email message</param>
        /// <param name="bodyHtml">Body property of that message</param>
        /// <param name="imageResizeRatio">New ratio for image</param>
        /// <returns>String used for new body for UI to display</returns>
        private static string PopulateInlineImages(MimeMessage newMessage, string bodyHtml, double imageResizeRatio = 1)
        {
            // encode as base64 for easier downloading/storage 
            if (bodyHtml != null)
            {
                foreach (MimePart att in newMessage.BodyParts)
                {
                    if (att.ContentId != null && att.Content != null && att.ContentType.MediaType == "image" && (bodyHtml.IndexOf("cid:" + att.ContentId, StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1))
                    {
                        byte[] b;
                        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            att.Content.DecodeTo(mem);
                            b = ReduceSize(mem, imageResizeRatio);
                            //b = mem.ToArray();
                        }
                        string imageBase64 = "data:" + att.ContentType.MimeType + ";base64," + System.Convert.ToBase64String(b);
                        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.Replace("cid:" + att.ContentId, imageBase64);
                    }
                }
            }
            return bodyHtml;
        }

        private static byte[] ReduceSize(Stream stream, double imageResizeRatio = 1)
        {
            Image source = Image.FromStream(stream);
            Image thumbnail = source.GetThumbnailImage((int)(source.Width * imageResizeRatio), (int)(source.Height * imageResizeRatio), AbortCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thumbnail.Save(memory, source.RawFormat);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private static bool AbortCallback()
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: use SkiaSharp for cross platform image/drawing tools

Comment: I've done a fruitless search for using that library for my situation. In fact, one link I found from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Resize?view=skiasharp-1.68.1) states "Warning This API is now obsolete." By any chance, do you have any sites/sources that would have a solid example for creating an Image from a stream, resizing it, and allowing it to be output to byte array in SkiaSharp?

Comment: if you look at the details, it has been replaced by ScalePixels() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.scalepixels?view=skiasharp-1.68.1

Comment: I appreciate the quick replies, Jason. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck. When I try "SKBitmap bm = SKBitmap.Decode(new SKManagedStream(stream));" I get a Null (indicating an error), however the stream is fine...Decode is failing. Also, I realize that StackOverflow will prefer this would move to chat...but I'm not seeing how to do that (DOH!). Once I get it to SKBitmap, I think I'll be golden!

Comment: are you sure your stream contains valid image data?  And have you tried decoding `stream` directly - I don't think SKManagedStream is necessary.

Comment: Yes...the stream definitely has valid image data because the old code using Image.FromStream(stream) works fine. But that code will not work in Xamarin, hence I'm trying to find a workaround. I'm guessing the SKManagedStream(stream) might be the wrong way to represent my Stream stream value, but no idea what other method might work. I wish the Decode would actually show me the error.

Comment: there is Decode overload that takes a System.IO.Stream.  What format is your image data in?

Comment: Oddly enough....System.IO.Stream which is how the method's parameter is defined. The originating data going into that method is a MemoryStream that was decoded from the original email data (att.Content.DecodeTo(mem)). Yeah...I know...I'm stumped.

Comment: can you post the image data somewhere so I can look at it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Even if the image wasn't confidential (which it is), our company limits our ability to use public cloud storage (like Google Drive, etc.). It's just weird that Image.FromStream(stream) works fine for the identical stream (outside of Xamarin). Soooo close....but sooo far....

Comment: Image is in System.Drawing, which is heavily tied to GDI and not available cross-platform.  I suspect the image data you're using is some oddball format that Windows happens to support.  That's why I asked you about the image format - if you open it with an image editor, what specific format is it in?  You can also try submitting a private test case to Xamarin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204571/discussion-between-prethen-and-jason).

Comment: For the moment, I have given up on trying to reduce the images and simply display the email HTML body as-is and it works fine...all images display perfectly well. The only thing I cannot get to work is decoding the image part of the email that will allow me to manipulate and resize it and get it back into a byte array.

Comment: You might need to reset the stream position after calling `att.Content.DecodeTo(mem);`. e.g. `mem.Position = 0;`